# Option to limit displayed length of text strings in data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

Some columns in data.tables can have content that is quite long (nchar(.) is large). This can sometimes make it difficult to inspect the whole data.table in R, since it will break after the wide columns. At the same time the information stored in the wide column may still be needed, so simply doing something along the lines of `DT[, long_strings := substr(long_strings, 1, max_length)]` is not a good solution.

Is there an option with which the display length of text can be controlled, so to make text columns in data.table be displayed denser than they are?

Comment: You cold try `DT[, lapply(.SD, substr, 1, 5)]` for instance if you want only to print without actually modifying the content. You could also use `.SDcols` in order to specify the `character` cols. There is also an issue on GH regarding `print.data.table` which you are welcome to contribute to https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1523

Answer (score 1):

you can use javasript in dt table

```
datatable(df, options = list(scrollX = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(
          targets = "_all",render = JS(
            "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
            "return type === 'display' && data.length > 70 ?",
            "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 70) + '...</span>' : data;",
            "}")
        )))))
```

were df is you dataframe.
this code limit to 70 chars

hope this help =)

Answer (score 0):

```
# create some data
library("data.table")
out <- NULL
a <- (round(runif(20,1,50)))
for(z in 1:length(a)){
  b <- paste(sample(c(letters[], rep(" ", 5)), a[z], replace = T), collapse="")
  out <- c(out, b)
}

DT = data.table(x=out, y=c(1,3), v=1:10)

# notice that its difficult to maintain an overview
DT

# a way to see only the first 5 characters of all elements 
View(as.data.frame(substr(as.matrix(DT), 1,5)))
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I think we search a way to control the display length of a table.

Comment: Of a `data.table`

Comment: You could just do `DT[, lapply(.SD, substr, 1, 5)]`